# Catch Error to Throw Exception

Tags: java

I am working with the `ClassLoader` class and if there are problems it throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`. In context this is actually not a fatal error.

Is there a good way to catch the error and throw as exception?

```
try{
    myClassLoader.makeClass(className, classData);
}
catch(Throwable t){
    log.error("Class load failed");
    // throw as an Exception instead
}
```

Does this make sense? I don't want this to be fatal but rather just exit without return. The key here is that I want the full stack trace and information associated with the `NoClassDefFoundError`. It is simple to catch the error it is harder to keep all of the associated information.

Comment: You mean like `catch(NoClassDefFoundError dfe)` ?

Comment: Don't forget syntax. (You appear to be missing 2 semicolons at first glance)

Comment: @Ascalonian Is there a good way to convert the Error to an Exception without losing  without losing any information?

Comment: What about `catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) { throw new Exception("Class load failed.", e); }`?

Comment: @bobbel blah didn't see the second constructor for Exception with throwable. That was dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
throw new Exception("message", t);
```

t is Throwable

Comment: This is the correct answer to a bad question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception and throw a new one very easily.

```
try{
    myClassLoader.makeClass(className, classData);
}catch(ClassNotFoundException err){
    throw new Exception("Oh no! An error occurred!");
}
```

Comment: The problem here is the difference between Error type and Exception. I am trying to convert Error to exception, I know how to handle a ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @bwfcwalshy's answer, we should never catch errors in a Java program. Consider a scenario where program runs out of memory, in this case, an `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown. If we have catch block to catch `Error` (or `Throwable`), it will catch that error but won't have memory to execute anything, resulting in that error getting suppressed.

We should always catch `Exception`, not `Error` or `Throwable`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you wouldn't catch a `java.lang.Error`.

But assuming that this is really what you want to do, you can just catch the Error and throw an Exception.

```
try {
  // Error occurred
} catch(Error e){
  throw new Exception("Error", e);
}
```